# Как создать покер один на один?

Tags: скрипт, php

Всем привет. Хотел поинтересоваться, какой алгоритм для скрипта по созданию покера один на один. Вообще хотелось бы узнать, с чего начать, какие языки нужно знать, на каком языке писать. Хотелось бы реализовать но есть знания только в html css php и немного в javascript. Подскажите люди добрые хоть что нибудь касательно создания такого проекта. Любая информация поможет. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начни с чего-нибудь попроще, например, -- со стандартной игрушки, из серии "три в ряд" с регистрацией игроков и рейтингом. Попробуй реализовать её как приложение ВК. Посмотри, через сколько суток появятся первые признаки хаков. Делай выводы, учись писать проверки безопасности, начинай заново. И так пока не твоя игрушка не станет достаточно защищённой, чтобы желающие накручивать в ней рейтинг перевелись.

Из языков тебе понадобится:

- Язык клиентской части, для веб-приложений это, обычно, JS, так как он поддерживается всеми браузерами, без лишних телодвижений. На "чистом" JS ты вряд ли потянешь написание чего-то серьёзного, так что выбери себе стороннюю библиотеку по вкусу (я использую jQuery, но это не панацея) и изучи её от и до, особенно всё, что касается AJAX запросов. 
  Имей в виду: Весь JS выполняется браузером, так что любой код и его поведение пользователь легко можно наблюдать и изменять из консоли. Поэтому вся логика игры и все запросы к БД должны быть строго на стороне сервера, клиент должен только показывать пользователю происходящее в игре, не более.
- Язык серверной части. Для простеньких логических игр сойдёт и PHP + библиотека, для работы с БД (я, для этих целей, использую ADODB), для покеррума лучше выучить что-то помощнее, например один из фреймворков Ruby (Rails, Sinatra, Padrino), или, ещё лучше, один из компилируемых языков.
- В любом случае, говоря о покерруме, стоит помнить, что они всегда используют собственные клиенты, с возможностью установки на компьютер пользователя. Если хочешь заняться этим всерьёз -- учись работать с C++, JS и Qt, эта связка поможет тебе в написании как кросплатформенного клиента, так и сервера.
- Дополнительно проштудируй всё связанное с HTTP и SQL запросами и стандартами HTML5 и CSS3.

Другой вариант -- изучить Flash или Java, но тут я не спец. В любом случае, это не будет проще, чем вышеописанный вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Цель?

Игра с компом? - да на чем угодно писать можно, php+js тоже пойдет.

PvP по какому-то своему протоколу? - В этом я не силен.

Написать бота и нагибать румы? - Забудь. Вот серьезно, забудь. Это задача очень и очень серьезная, только время и деньги просадишь. Говорю как человек который этим занимался) Впрочем если ты упрям, то можешь начать с обзорной информации [здесь](http://www.poker-bot.ru/)

Comment: спасибо вы очень помогли. я хотел бы сделать такую вещь, люди играют друг с другом на деньги. Например вход по 5 баксов, победитель выйгрывает все. я получаю комиссию примерно процентов 10. вот такой план капкан

Comment: Ну эта идея далеко не нова и онлайн покеррумов несметные тыщи) 
Я не знаю деталей реализации, но там очень серьезные требования к безопасности, плюс вообще множество нюансов которые возникают всегда когда есть люди и деньги.
Задача поднять новый рум так чтобы он окупился выглядит неподъемной для одного разработчика, тем более малоопытного.

Comment: хм. это да, просто если сам с нуля пишешь то практически затраты твои сводятся к нулю. Просто чем это будет отличаться от казино, казино всегда в выграше, и люди понимают это и боятся, а тут ты играешь с живым человеком или ты выйграл или проиграл но это реальный человек. Я понимаю что подводных камней куча, но я бы смог тратить пару часиков вечером для реализации это идеи.! Просто вот с чего начать нужно определится.

Comment: для реализации node.js